# Reading large binary file that does not fit into memory and calculate mean across axis 0

Tags: numpy

I have a `binary` file of very big size.
Its shape is (1000, 20000, 20000).
I needed to calculate `np.nanmean(axis=0)`.

How can I calculate mean across axis 0?

I tried as.

```
indata = np.memmap(file, mode='r', shape=(10000, 20000, 20000), dtype=np.float32)
```

It reads correctly.

Then, trying for `nanmean` calculation:

```
result = np.nanmean(indata,axis=0)
```

It does not fit into memory and the shell is restarted due to memory error

Comment: `np.memmap()` is for mapping pure binary files without headers rather than for `.npy` files. I think you want https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.lib.format.open_memmap.html#numpy.lib.format.open_memmap

Comment: What is the actual format of the file? the title claims .npy but this is not clear in the question.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy its binary file, it has been read correctly, but the problem with mean calculation. I have edited it.

Comment: You previously gave a line of code in your question that you claim writes your data file which is many terabytes in size. When you ran it, it runs instantly, so surely you can see that the data is not written to disk? The issue is unlikely to be reading the file and more likely writing it. Please try the code I gave in my answer and see if that works on your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at saving and reading a Numpy array, two different ways:

- as a headerless, binary file, and
- as a `.NPY` format file with a header describing the `dtype` and shape

---

```
import numpy as np

# Create 100 element array of 8-byte floats
w, h = 10, 10          # width and height
a = np.arange(h*w, dtype=float).reshape((h,w))
```

Now we save that array first as pure, headerless binary data and secondly as a `.NPY` file:

```
a.tofile('data.bin')
np.save('data.npy', a)
```

The first thing to note is that `data.bin` is exactly 800 bytes, i.e. 100 floats of 8 bytes each. On the other hand, `data.npy` is 928 bytes because it has a header that describes the shape, and dtype of the array.

Now we can read the binary file, noting that we must specify the shape and dtype because there is no header:

```
r = np.memmap('data.bin', float, shape=(h,w))
np.all(r==a)     # Check arrays are identical - prints True
```

Now we can read the `.NPY` file, noting we don't need to specify the shape and dtype because it's in the header:

```
b = np.lib.format.open_memmap('data.npy')
np.all(b==a)     # Check arrays are identical - prints True
```

Now you can calculate your mean with:

```
mean = np.nanmean(b, axis=0)
```

Comment: nice, upvoted. Then, what would be the best practice to calculate `result = np.nanmean(indata,axis=0)` ?

Comment: I have added in the calculation of the mean - please take another look.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is memory error on the calculation of nanmean. `mean = np.nanmean(b, axis=0)` Could you see my edit in the question ?

Comment: Please update your code - as it stands it doesn't write anything in the file.

Comment: The input binary file (.bin) is of around 500 GB which has now be read by `np.memmap`. But when I calculate `nanmean` the program ends without completing the task (memry error)

Comment: If you do this `outdata = np.memmap('data.bin', mode='w+', shape=(10000, 20000, 20000), dtype=np.float32)` it creates a file that looks to be 15TB in size. Check with `ls -lh data.bin` and you'll see `-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff    15T 28 May 14:48 data.bin` ***BUT*** check with `ls -ls data.bin` and you can see it only takes 32 blocks on disk and is sparse  `32 -rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  16000000000000 28 May 14:48 data.bin`